# The most efficient way to find the top level parent in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given the following table

```
catName     catID     parentID
=================================
vehicles    1         0
cars        2         1
sedans      3         2
animals     4         0
cows        5         4
```

Given a `catID`, I need to find its top level parent (`parentID = 0`).

This query is executed 50-100 times a day. There are currently 100-200 rows (maybe more in the future). Up to 8 levels deep. I'm thinking three alternatives:

1. Using a recursive method
2. Creating a view
3. Adding another column `topParentID` (least favorable)

Which will be the most efficient?

Comment: Can you add the expected output also `Mysql` or `sql server` because `Mysql` <> `Sql server`

Comment: Run only 100 times per day on 200 rows, the performance requirement is vanishingly small. Why do you care about the most efficient?Unless I've misunderstood your question (in which case it needs clarifying) this is micro-optimisation and should be ignored until you see you have a problem.

Comment: I haven't implemented this yet. I'm starting now, so I want to know where to start.

Comment: Look for recursive cte.

Comment: Another option that you can look at are nested sets. [This](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) article does a pretty good job explaining them and comparing them to the hierarchical model that you currently have in place. I have been using this method to map out our companies organizational structure in our data warehouse and it has been working really well. The article is written with MySql in mind, but the example queries all use standard syntax. One note though, insertions can be lengthy depending on how many records you have in the sets.

Comment: If you though for future and if it will get larger within some times(within 1 or 2 yr). then good to go with third option. If beyond that , then recursive cte is good.

Comment: Thanks NoDisplayName, I ended up using recursive cte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL2008+:

To store hierarchies , SQL Server includes [HIERARCHYID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx) data type. Above data can be "converted" to use `HIERARCHYID` "values" thus:

```
catName     catID     parentID  hierarchyNode
=============================================
vehicles    1         0         /1/
cars        2         1         /1/2/
sedans      3         2         /1/2/3/
animals     4         0         /4/
cows        5         4         /4/5/
```

After conversion, I would drop `parentID` column.

HIERARCHYID is SQLCLR system data type which include following [methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677193.aspx):

- HidValue.[GetLevel()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677197.aspx)
- HidValue.[GetAncestor(level)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677202.aspx).

To get parent node I would use these methods thus:

```
DECLARE @node HIERARCHYID
SET     @node = '/1/2/3/'

SELECT  
    currentNodeLvl= @node.GetLevel(),                                 --> 3
    parentAsHID   = @node.GetAncestor(@node.GetLevel() - 1),          --> 0x58
    parentAsString= @node.GetAncestor(@node.GetLevel() - 1).ToString()--> /1/
```

More, I would create an index on `hierarchyNode` column thus:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IUN_Table_hierarchyNode
ON dbo.Table(hierarchyNode)
```

and final query will be:

```
SELECT ..., prt.catID AS parentID
FROM dbo.Table crt -- Curent node
LEFT/INNER JOIN -- It depends on hierarchyID nullability 
dbo.MyTable prt -- Parent node
ON @node.GetAncestor(crt.hierarchyID.GetLevel() - 1).ToString() = prt.hierarchyID
```

Comment: I love HierarchyID and think that it's very underused.

Answer (score 2):

### TLDR

For large data sets, use a bridge table.

---

### Bridge table details

At scale (data warehouse scale), the most efficient way I know to solve this is via a bridge table.  Check out http://www.askjohnobiee.com/2013/08/how-to-bridge-tables-and-many-to-many.html for the basics.

You end up maintaining a physical table that has a row which matches every parent object to *every* child and subchild object (and from each object to itself).  It's maintenance heavy (since it has to be updated whenever any of the relationships change), but it's extremely efficient to query, even for large data sets.

In your example, I'd build (and fill) a bridge table with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE BridgeCategories
(
 ParentCategoryID int,
 ParentCategoryLevel tinyint,
 ChildCategoryID int,
 ChildCategoryLevel tinyint,
 PRIMARY KEY (ParentCategoryID, ChildCategoryID)
)

-- add an index for your particular query
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_BridgeCategories_ByChildIDAndParentLevel
ON BridgeCategories (ChildCategoryID, ParentCategoryLevel) INCLUDE (ParentCategoryID)
```

When you populate the `BridgeCategories` table, I'd set the appropriate levels according to how far down they are in the hierarchy (ie, in your example, category ID 1 - "vehicles" would have a level of 0, while ID 2 - "sedans" would have a level of 2).

In your example, (I think) the following query would fill a bridge table with the above structure, assuming your source table is called **`DimCategories`**.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE BridgeCategories;

declare @currentLevel tinyint;
declare @MAX_LEVELS tinyint;

set @currentLevel = 0;
set @MAX_LEVELS = 16;

-- seed your root level entries
insert into BridgeCategories
SELECT
    catID, @currentLevel, catID, @currentLevel
from DimCategories c
WHERE
    c.parentID = 0;

set @currentLevel = @currentLevel + 1

while (@currentLevel < @MAX_LEVELS)
BEGIN
    -- add any current level parent -> child mappings   
    insert into BridgeCategories
    SELECT
        b.ParentCategoryID,
        b.ParentCategoryLevel,
        c.catID,
        @currentLevel
    from BridgeCategories b
    join DimCategories c
        on b.ChildCategoryID = c.parentID


    -- add the current level self-referencing entries
    insert into BridgeCategories
    SELECT
        c.catID,
        @currentLevel,
        c.catID,
        @currentLevel
    from BridgeCategories b
    join DimCategories c
        on b.ChildCategoryID = c.parentID
    group by c.catID

    set @currentLevel = @currentLevel + 1
end
```

With this structure in place, you could run the following query to get the root parent catID of any @catID.

```
select
  ParentCategoryID
from BridgeCategories b
where
  b.ChildCategoryID = @catID
  and b.ParentCategoryLevel = 0
```

You can look up more information on Ralph Kimball data warehousing concepts if you want to dive deeper.

Comment: Thanks for an extensive answer. I will make sure to keep it in mind for later. Thanks for taking your time and providing your knowledge.